# Discord.py hangman game - problem with bot recognizing positions of guessed letters

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py

Im trying to create a hangman game in discord.py. Now i have been trying to figure out how to continue. The bot simply chooses random word from a list and then sends embed message with instructions and image of hangman *(the image below is just for example, there will be only ground at the beginning of course)* and finally number of underscores depending on lenght of the word. *(wanted to do it with for loop but it doesnt work because the message wouldnt be in one line)*. Now i dont know how to continue. For example the word is **beer** and someone types **e** so the outcome should be that the bot sends another message but this time with **e** letters **(__ e e __)** but i dont know how to make the bot recognize where are the positions of the guessed letter and then how to send it.

[image: Here is the beginning of the game in discord]

```
words = ["car","beer","patient",......]
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 60.0, commands.BucketType.guild)
async def hangman(msg):
    if msg.channel.id != channel:
        return
    guessed_letters = []
    word = str(random.choice(words))
    word_len = len(word)
    e = discord.Embed(color=3447003)
    e.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/nYgwk8M.png")
    await msg.send("**HANGMAN** (Guess by sending letters)",embed=e)
    if word_len == 3:
        await msg.send("**__** **__** **__**")
    if word_len == 4:
        await msg.send("**__** **__** **__** **__**")
    if word_len == 5:
        await msg.send("**__** **__** **__** **__** **__**")
    if word_len == 6:
        await msg.send("**__** **__** **__** **__** **__** **__**")
    if word_len == 7:
        await msg.send("**__** **__** **__** **__** **__** **__** **__**")
    if word_len == 8:
        await msg.send("**__** **__** **__** **__** **__** **__** **__** **__**")
    if word_len == 9:
        await msg.send("**__** **__** **__** **__** **__** **__** **__** **__** **__**")
    def checkhangman(message):
        return message.content in ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
    guess = await bot.wait_for("message", check=checkhangman)
    if str(guess) in word:
        guessed_letters.append(str(guess))
        #For example someone types e and the word is beer, so the outcome will be:
        await msg.send("**__** **e** **e** **__**")
        ...
        #And then the game continues
    else:
        #Here if the guess is not in the word, the bot will send another image of hangman and the game continues
        e = discord.Embed(color=3447003)
        e.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/nYgwk8M.png")
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't related to the question, but those `if-statements` for the length hurt me a bit. You don't have to hardcode every single possible length in there, you're better off just joining a list of them with a space.

I'm not sure what you mean with

> doesn't work because message wouldn't be in one line

because you can just add them to a string without newlines & then it'll be one line.

```py
underscores = "**" + " ".join(["__" for _ in range(word_len)]) + "**"
```

In order to get the letters in there, you can just iterate over your word and add an underscore if the current letter has not been guessed yet. If the letter *has* been guessed, you can show the letter.

```py
word = "beer"  # The current word
guessed_letter = "e"  # Currently guessed letter
guessed = ["a", "c", "d"]  # List of all guessed letters

l = []  # List of characters to join back into a string

guessed.append(guessed_letter)  # Add guessed letter to the list of letters

for letter in word:  # Check every letter in the word to see if it has been guessed
    if letter in guessed:
        l.append(letter)  # Show the letter if it has been guessed
    else:
        l.append("\_\_")  # Otherwise show an underscore, EDIT: escape them

# "l" now contains the string that should be sent back
underscores = "**" + " ".join(l) + "**"

await msg.send(underscores)
```

You can also use `string += string` instead of `string.join()`, but then you'll have to remove an extra space that was added at the end. No big deal, but I prefer using `join` to make my life easier.

EDIT:

__a__ is markdown syntax to underline something on Discord, so you have to escape the underscores using backslashes.

Comment: Seems to work, also i had to change underscores with dashes because for some reason underscores just didnt work.

Comment: "\_\_a\_\_" is markdown syntax to underline a character, so if a letter is filled in then it will be underlined instead. You'll have to escape the underscores (add 1 symbol), I've edited my answer.